# IIF(Field.Value) IN List then this Value in SSRS 2016

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

```
IIF(First(Fields!PID.Value, "Group_Info") IN (3444,3555,3678,3989,4005,4100), "$85"
OR IIF (First(Fields!PID.Value, "Group_Info) IN (3456,3558,3645,3859,3958,4011,4300) "$75"
```

Is there a way to do this? I know that you cannot use "IN", I just don't know the expression that you would use.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
=SWITCH(
First(Fields!PID.Value,Group_Info").Contains("3444","3555","3678","3989","4005","4100"),"$85"
,First(Fields!PID.Value,Group_Info").Contains("3456","3558","3645","3859","3958","4011","4300"),"$75"
)
```